# How to display the numbers in graph?

Tags: core-plot

How to display the custom number in X and Y axis?
I need to display my custom subject name in x axis, Marks in Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `labelTextStyle` and `labelFormatter` on the plot to create automatic data labels. This will work with any plot type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eric.
I have solved this issue with help of custom label.
I have used `axisLabels` property.